# VSCode debug Typescript Error with sourceMap enabled

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a typescript app. The src is in the src directory. If i run the build, and start the app, it works. Now I want to debug it. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-tutorial#_debugging

The typescript is in module format. The output which will be generated in the disk directory has no module, because the tsconfig.json file has the option set.

So, the problem is, if I make the config of the tasks.json, launch.json and run debug, it won't work. It's a node app.

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
      "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/*.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "typescript",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "problemMatcher": ["$tsc"]
    }
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true ,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true ,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true ,
    "outDir": "./dist" ,
    "sourceRoot": "./src/",
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
    "strict": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The Error tells me: (Trigger after I click Start Debugging Button in VSCode F5)

```
PS C:\Users\ruper\Documents\Code\javaScript\microtrading>  ${env:NODE_OPTIONS}='--require c:/Users/ruper/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly-2022.5.2017/src/bootloader.bundle.js --inspect-publish-uid=http'; ${env:VSCODE_INSPECTOR_OPTIONS}='{"inspectorIpc":"\\\\.\\pipe\\node-cdp.3248-1.sock","deferredMode":false,"waitForDebugger":"","execPath":"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe","onlyEntrypoint":false,"autoAttachMode":"always","fileCallback":"C:\\Users\\ruper\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\node-debug-callback-5c4d148c5f27f944"}'; & 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe' '.\src\index.ts' 
Debugger attached.
(node:22324) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
C:\Users\ruper\Documents\Code\javaScript\microtrading\src\index.ts:1
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Comment: Did you try setting "type": "module" in the package.json file as the error message mentions.

Comment: Also, in your tsconfig does changing to `"module": "CommonJS",` (note capitalization) help?  That is what I get intellisense showing me.

Comment: @Mark in package.json it's the default value: so CommonJS. Changing the cap don't help.